# How to delete "<QuerySet[]>" from the json response "<QuerySet [data]>"?

Tags: python, django

I'm sending data in json but the output is like this:

```
{
  "ids": "<QuerySet [dafa1, lnvq2]>"
}
```

and I want it just like this:

```
{
  "ids": "dafa1, lnvq2"
}
```

here's the code I'm using:

```
from upload.models import Images
from django.http import JsonResponse

def list(request):
    ids = Images.objects.filter(allowed=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
    data = {
        'ids': str(ids),
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to run `for ... in ...` and add those elements to the string, before adding to the dictionary.

```
from upload.models import Images
from django.http import JsonResponse

def list(request):
    ids_string = ''
    ids = Images.objects.filter(allowed=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
    for id in ids:
        ids_string += str(id)
    data = {
        'ids': ids_string,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in [**`join()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [**`map()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) functions as,

```
def some_good_name(request):
    ids = Images.objects.filter(allowed=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
    data = {
        'ids': ", ".join(map(str, ids))
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**Note:** Change your name of the view function from ***list*** since it is **reserved keyword in Python**

Comment: I used str() because of this error Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable and even if I serialize it it doesn't fix my problem. thanks anyway

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using safe=False?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar That was a mistake. Thanks tho

Comment: python just crashed